# websphere 8.5.5.6 server having java 6 and 7 but i need java 8 how to add java sdk to existing websphere server

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, java-8, websphere-8

i installed was 8.5.5.6 in my system. when i am trying to add in eclipse its showing Jre run-time environment as

1. Web sphere application server java 1.6,  64 bit and
2. Web sphere application server java 1.7, 64 bit

---

But i need to work on java 1.8 which is already installed but server jre is not there default java 1.7 is there
my question is how to add or upgrade Java 1.8 in web sphere

when i tried to run the server its showing below error:

WebSphere Application Server error
WebSphere Application Server error

> The xxxxxx project is built with Java SDK 8, which is not
>   compatible with the server running at Java SDK 7. Try publishing the
>   application on a later version of WebSphere Application Server.  Or
>   try increasing the JRE of the server, if you are using WebSphere
>   Application Server V8.5. The xxxx project is built with Java SDK
>   1.8, which is not compatible with the server running at Java SDK 7. Try publishing the application on a later version of WebSphere
>   Application Server.  Or try increasing the JRE of the server, if you
>   are using WebSphere Application Server V8.5. The xxxxxx
>   project is built with Java SDK 1.8, which is not compatible with the
>   server running at Java SDK 7. Try publishing the application on a
>   later version of WebSphere Application Server.  Or try increasing the
>   JRE of the server, if you are using WebSphere Application Server V8.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 8 is only supported by WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.6. If you use the WebSphere Application Server Full Profile, only Java 7 and 6 are supported.

Comment: So  8.5.5.6 itself having two versions? full and liberty? so 
1. i need to un install this version and install liberty version of same?
2. or is there Any alternative like adding java 8 to existing version

Comment: @saideshkilaru WebSphere Application Server (traditional aka full) and WebSphere Liberty Profile are two different runtimes. They are since 8.5, so it is not new in 8.5.5.6. Liberty is new lightweight runtime, but it doesn't support all the features of traditional WAS. If you have existing WAS full environment you cannot use Java 8 now (probably in next major release). If you are creating new environment, then you can use WebSphere Liberty Profile, it is available for download either through passport advantage or via http://wasdev.net/

Comment: WebSphere Liberty is a different product (it has just the same version). Have a look at https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/ for the Liberty profile. You can install both products at the same time. There is no possibility to add Java 8 to WAS itself.

Comment: i downloaded https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/runtimes-8.5.5-webprofile7-ibm-java this version but unable to find exe file to install any help?

Comment: There is no exe file. Just download the ZIP and unpack it. You don't have to install WebSphere Liberty.

Comment: no need to install? then how can i work with that in eclipse how can i add a server with jav 8 jre please help me.

Comment: while defining a server in eclipse using was 8 pluginn it will ask for  installation directory of was r8? i tried giving  D:\Softwares\wlp-webProfile7-java8-win-x86_64-8.5.5.6\wlp path but its giving an error like
"The WebSphere Application Server installation directory is not correct"

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, but as far as i know, for WebSphere Liberty you have to install separate Developer Tools. So go to the Eclipse Marketplace, and search for Liberty.

Comment: Also might be worth reviewing this slideshare deck and transcript on what WAS Liberty is: http://www.slideshare.net/wasdevnet/aai-1304liberty-profileoverview-46815723. 

The eclipse tooling can be installed from here: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-eclipse/

You need to use a different server adapter when you create the server from WAS Classic though.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 is now available on Full WAS 8.5.5.9.
It can be downloaded from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24041819#SDK80).
Java 8 is only supported on these [Operating Systems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27045339).

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 is now supported on WebSphere classic profile by the 8.5.5.9 fix pack according to the documentation here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27005002

> WebSphere 8.5.5 Java 8.0 (Liberty only from 8.5.5.5, Classic WebSphere from 8.5.5.9)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. I hope it will help future users.

1) I upgraded to 8.5.5.10 
2) Go to below page 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042600#SDK80 
and then click on first link ("Java SDK 8.0.3.0 ..." link) 
3) Click to download appropriate file. (for Windows, 8.0.3.0-WS-IBMWASJAVA-Win.zip) 
4) Extract the file to some location 
5) Open IBM installation manager and configure the repository as above location 
6) Then click on Install link on installation manager 
7) Select appropriate update (IBM Java SDK for app. server) 
8) Then just go further to install successfully 
9) Start the server and go the below path  
   Application servers > server1 > Java SDKs
You will see now both Java 8 as well as Java 6. 
10) Select Java 8 and click on make default. 
11) Restart the server. 
12) Thats it

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to path where websphere is installed
   C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\bin
2. managesdk.bat –listAvailabl
3. managesdk.bat -listEnabledProfile -profileName {Profile name ex - AppSrv01 }  -verbose
4. managesdk.bat -enableProfile -profileName {Profile name ex - AppSrv01 }  -sdkname 1.7_32{or 1.7_64} –enableServers
5. Close RAD (if it is open)
6. Reopen RAD
7. Right click the server configured with JDK 7 runtime in the servers view > Properties > WebSphere Application Server.

The JVM Version should now be at the value of sdkname (for example 1.7_64 as seen below):

8. Publish your application in RAD